# Do I need to be an App Hub member for an internal app

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm creating a small Windows 7 Phone app for our company. It is an internal app and will not be put on the market. First I need to test it on a real phone. Once it has passed the test, the staff will install it on their phone. Do I need to be an App Hub member for testing and deploying my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to jailbreak your Windows Phones: **Yes**.

You will need this account to be able to side load (load non-market apps) to your phone and debug them. Beware, dev accounts have a limited number of phone they can be linked to (5 from memory).

As always you can bypass this by jailbreaking but you will need to do it on every phone.